# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space using Docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker-compose, spark-submit

So I am running the following locally (standalone):

```
~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --py-files afile.py run_script.py
```

And I got the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

To overpass this I am running the following:

```
~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 6G --executor-memory 1G --py-files afile.py run_script.py
```

and the script runs normally.

Now, I am using the following [docker build for Spark](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark) and run the following:

```
docker-compose up
docker exec app_master_1 bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 6G --executor-memory 1G --py-files afile.py run_script.py
```

In that case I still get the error of:

```
2018-06-13 21:43:16 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9, 172.17.0.3, executor 0): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter.write(UnsafeRowWriter.java:219)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:140)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.next(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.fold(TraversableOnce.scala:212)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.fold(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$19.apply(RDD.scala:1090)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$19.apply(RDD.scala:1090)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2123)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and somewhere later:

```
2018-06-13 21:43:17 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl:70 - Lost executor 0 on 172.17.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages
```

As far as I undersand even though its written that its out of memory in executor 0 i have to increase the driver-memory as its a standalone, right??

Any idea why is this happening and how to overpass it?

*edit*

The error is happening when i am trying to use `sqlCont.read.json(json_path)` where the file is not even big enough.

Comment: Can you share full stacktrace? Are you multiple containers? where you getting this error?

Comment: @Kaushal I have updated the answer a bit. I am just using the docker-compose of the link that provide which creates 2 containers: one master and one worker.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L34), Worker node is initialized with 1 GB memory in your docker script and you executing spark-submit command with 1 GB memory for executor, so either you decrease executor memory or increase your worker memory while you creating docker container.

Comment: I don't think it's right. SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY is defining -Xmx for worker JVM, and executor JVMs are spun up separately and their Xmx is controlled by `--executor-memory` as in OP post.

Comment: SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY specifies here docker containers memory, not the JVM. Executor JVM runs within worker container, so anyway if you have increased `--executor-memory` it won't affect because the container itself having less memory